# How to make a correct Json Deserialization to a Java Object?

Tags: java, json, gson

I really need help here, im  Deserializing the next json:

```
{
    "name":"myname",
    "userID":"12345",
    "password":"sha1passwordASDESFSGSD",
    "active":"1",
    "profile":"2",
    "job":"Manager"
}
```

Im using Jersey to create webService, when i recive the json i recive it as a InputStream

Also i tried with a String

```
@POST
@Path("user/in/")
@Produces("application/json")
public String InsertUser(InputStream inStr) 
{
    String line = null, res = "POST 200 > ";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStr));
    try {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            res += line;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        UserInformation user = new Gson().fromJson(res, UserInformation.class);
        System.out.println("All done");
        System.out.println(user.getName());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error al convertir jo object " + e.getCause() + e.getMessage());
    }

    return "POST 200 > ";
}
```

I tried using a InputStreamReader:

```
@POST
@Path("user/in/")
@Produces("application/json")
public String InsertUser(InputStream inStr)
{
    try {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inStr);
        UserInformation user = new Gson().fromJson(isr, UserInformation.class);
        System.out.println("All done");

        System.out.println(user.getName());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error al convertir jo object " + e.getCause() + e.getMessage());
    }

    return "POST 200 > ";
}
```

Neither of those codes work. They don't throw an exception or print "All done".
When i debug the object, `user` doesn't appear in the variables menu.
In my experience, is because an error is happening in the line `UserInformation user = new Gson().fromJson(isr, UserInformation.class);`

But i cant see which one is.

My UserInformation Class is the next

```
public class UserInformation {

    private String name;
    private String userID;
    private String password;
    private String active;
    private String profile;
    private String job;

    // Methods removed for brevity
}
```

Comment: `User` or `UserInformation`?

Comment: Please paste the stacktrace for the exception.

Comment: Sorry, is UserInformation the name of the class, the inStr is the InputStream that my class recive, it has the json, i know it because in the second method, i use the BufferReadered and i print the Json

Comment: "none of the two codes works" What do they do? Are all the fields `null`?

Comment: Your first snippet works fine for me.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: I already edit my question,i really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Google gson. Here is my answer:

```
    @Post
    @Path("user/in")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response InsertUser(string json){
      JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(json);
      JsonObject object = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
      String name = object.getAsJsonPrimitive("name").getAsString();
      int userID = object.getAsJsonPrimitve("userID").getAsInt();
      String password = object.getAsJsonPrimitive("password").getAsString();
      String job = object.getAsJsonPrimitive("job").getAsString();
      int active = object.getAsJsonPrimitve("active").getAsInt();
      int profile = object.getAsJsonPrimitve("profile").getAsInt();



      return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("all done").build();


    }
```

Comment: You are right... my first thought was to return an object with it:
String s= gson.toJson("all done");
return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(s).build();

I changed my mind and forgot to clean the code

Comment: Thank you, it help me to resolve getting the values, But doest resolve the problem, how to converted into a java object.

Answer (score 0):

I already find the solution, the problem was that i was receiving a InputStream, 
following its recommendations the solution code is:

```
  @POST
  @Path("users/in/")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public String InsertUser(String json)
  { 

      try{
          UserInformation user = new Gson().fromJson(json, UserInformation.class);
          String name = user.getName();
          String userID = user.getUserID();                       
          String password = user.getPassword();
          String job = user.getJob();
          String active = user.getActive();
          String profile = user.getProfile();

      }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println(Response.status(500).entity(e.getCause() + e.getMessage()).build().toString());
          return Response.status(500).entity(e.getCause() + e.getMessage()).build().toString();
      }

  }
```